# python spur ssh - use set command

Tags: python, ssh

I am using the below commands to ssh into a windows server and I am trying to use the set command. This is what I am using locally which works:

```
set ASPERA_SCP_PASS=myPassword
ascp /directory/Test4.mov myAccount@10.1.1.1:/TEST
```

And here is my python commands:

```
shell = spur.SshShell(hostname=10.0.0.1, username=Wusername, password=Wpassword, missing_host_key=spur.ssh.MissingHostKey.accept)
result = shell.run(["set", "ASPERA_SCP_PASS=myPassword])
result = shell.run(["ascp.exe", "/directory/Test4.mov", "myAccount@10.1.1.1:/TEST"])
```

When running the above I am successfully connecting via ssh, but I am getting this error on the `set` command:

```
spur.results.RunProcessError: return code: 127
output: b''
stderr output: b'sh: line 0: exec: set: not found\n'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this worked fine:

```
environment = {}
environment["ASPERA_SCP_PASS"] = "password"
shell = spur.SshShell(hostname="10.1.1.1", username="username", password="passowrd", missing_host_key=spur.ssh.MissingHostKey.accept)
result = shell.run(["ascp.exe", directory, "Ausername@10.0.0.1:/"], stdout=sys.stdout, update_env=environment)
```